# Make a flash be a background in html(full screen)

Tags: html, css, flash

I made a 1920 * 1048 flash(for 16:9 screen),and embedded it into the html
like:

```
<div style="top:0;left:0;background-color:red;width:100%;height:100%;z-index:-10">
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="./img/bg.swf" frameborder=0 allowfullscreen> </iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the question:

In a 4:3 screen the flash's width is 100%,but there's white padding on the top and bottom. It seems the flash must keep aspect ratio.

Is there some way to make the flash full screen in 4:3 screen and 16:9 screen?

Or like the css syntax:

```
background:url(...) center center
```

the image always full screen, and in 4:3 screen only display a part of the image.

Comment: WHY on EARTH would you make a 1920 x 1048 flash object???

Comment: The background image is 1920px.It is right in every screen.But I must add some shinning effect,so I choose flash and made a big flash...

Comment: So I must make the shinning effect a smaller one? And in the html like that?: 

    <body style="background-image:url('1.png');">
        <div style="top:200px;left:0;z-index:-10">
        <iframe src="1.swf"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div style="top:100px;left:200px;z-index:-10">
        <iframe src="2.swf"></iframe>
        </div>
        <div style="top:150px;left:200px;z-index:-10">
        <iframe src="3.swf"></iframe>
        </div>
    </body>

But how can I make the swf fixed to the background image in every screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally make a static width&height page.The width is 1920px and height is 1048px

the flash's css like
    `style="position:relative;top:0;left:0;width:1920px;height:1048px;z-index:-10"`

and other div's css like
    `style="position:fixed;z-index:2;top:80px;left:30px;"`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` This should fix it. You can also do this for `body`

Comment: the white padding top and bottom also a flash."padding:0;margin:0"  seems not work. :(

Comment: did you try it in the css code like suggested with 'body' as well?

Comment: Like <style>body{ margin: 0; padding: 0;}  * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }</style> ? not work :(

Comment: try setting padding:0;margin:0;border:none; for the iframe. otherwise i have no more ideas.